# AngularJS & Angular to co-exists without upgrading angularjs code

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I've a single AngularJS application with various controllers/views/services and directives. I wish to move to angular and typescript without modifying the existing code. Is it possible to do this? I've seen various samples and forums where they convert existing directives/controllers to a component. Since my application is huge doing this would be a mammoth effort for us.

My question is different than other questions on StackOverflow because I don't want to modify my existing codebase but want both the code styles of Angular and AngularJS code to co-exists.

Comment: why do you want both versions?

Comment: Because my existing code base is pretty huge and i can't migrate that to angular 5 style component. It would be a huge effort and may introduce lot of errors. Hence I want, angularjs and angular to co-exists. It is fine, if I'm not able to re-use existing angularjs code in angular part. Just want to see all the possibilities to go about this.

Comment: why do you want to migrate to angular 5 and not continue development in angular js?

Comment: Because soon (may be a year or two), Angular team will stop official support to AngularJS. So better is upgrade to new version. And slowly migrate huge angularJS code to angular but in a phased manner.